# How to modify the existing list template file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, splist, list-template

I want to modify a list template which is already created in my site collection.Once I upload the list into the template gallery it becomes a .stp file.But how to modify this again?

I am having a requirement to change formula of one of the the list columns in this list and make available with this change.The site from which I have taken the list as a template is not existing now.I am using SP 2013.

Comment: You can try to download the `stp` file change extension to `rar` then extract it and see what you can do with the `manifest.xml` file.

Comment: Yes.I have already done this.I changed it to cab file and extracted to a  folder and opened the manifest.xml file.Now how to bring this back as a .stp file such that I can upload this in the list template galleryagain.

Comment: So Were you successful in doing it? No error?

Comment: Am at the manifest.xml updating step only.I did changes the and saved this xml file.Now how to get the cab or stp file again from this manifest.xml file.

Comment: Do `Right Click` on `manifest.xml` select `Add to manifest.rar`. Once you have a `rar` file then again change the extension to `.stp` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25485/discussion-between-samolpp-p-and-asad-refai).

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward way.

**But the best option** would be

1. create a new list based on that `List Template` on your new `Site Collection`
2. In the new list update the calculated formula of a column
3. Now save that list as a template.
4. Hence you will contain the latest `list template` which will contain the new calculated formula on a column.